# TypeError: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, int given in /var/www/html/ee242p1/vendor/laminas/laminas-escaper/src/Escaper.php:246

Tags: magento2.4.2, laminas

While doing some of the operations like product edit at admin side, viewing category pages facing an error as follows:

```
TypeError: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, int given in /var/www/html/ee242p1/vendor/laminas/laminas-escaper/src/Escaper.php:246
```

Full stack trace leads me to the laminas package.

```
TypeError: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, int given in /var/www/html/eee242p1/vendor/laminas/laminas-escaper/src/Escaper.php:246 
Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/eee242p1/vendor/laminas/laminas-escaper/src/Escaper.php(246): 
rawurlencode() #1 /var/www/html/eee242p1/vendor/magento/framework/Escaper.php(286): 
Laminas\Escaper\Escaper->escapeUrl() #2 /var/www/html/eee242p1/vendor/magento/framework/Url/RouteParamsResolver.php(115):
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the "laminas/laminas-escaper" module update issue. Try to set version 2.7.0 in composer.

> "laminas/laminas-escaper": "2.7.0"

Check details: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/33346

Answer (score 0):

thanks, you saved my life. Resolve by read this post, change composer.json and downgrade escaper.

F